# How do I force a regex to grab as little as possible?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex: `<<button (".*?")>>`

I have this string: `<<button "A string" "Another string">><</button>>`

This matches all the way to `<<button "A string" "Another string">>`, and I don't want to.  I want this to *not* match because there are 2 strings.

Here are some examples of what i want:

`<<button "A string" "Another string">><</button>>` No match

`<<button "A string">><</button>>` Match

`<<button>><</button>>` No match

I thought because I was using a non-greedy regex, this would work the way I wanted, but in my opinion it's acting pretty greedy. I may not understand what non-greedy means. How do I write a regex that works the way I want?

I am using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that greedy/non-greedy do not affect what is matched and what is not matched, but simply how long will be the matched part.
In other words your dot `.` will munch also double quotes if that is needed to make the whole expression to match.

Greedy will munch first as much as possible and then backtrack to shorter, non-greedy will munch as few as possible and backtrack to longer.

You need instead to parse the string... something like

```
<<button ("([^"\\]|\\.)*")>>
```

Meaning is

- `"` double quote
- `(...)*` zero or more of

  - `[^"\\]` NOT a backslash or a double quote
  - `|` or
  - `\\.` a backslash followed by any char
- `"` double quote

the problem with strings is that they can contain double-quotes if escaped with a backslash, so parsing a string requires more than just `"([^"]*)"`.

Comment: can you explain why I need to do this and what it's doing?

Comment: why do I need `\\.`? You seem to be focusing on writing a regex that allows escaped quotes which is good, but I'm more confused about why my non-greedy didn't work?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: `.` is anything, including double quotes. Non greedy never changes what you match or don't match, it simply decides what is that you matched. I'll add a note for that.

Comment: okay that's helpful. The last part I'm confused about is, why does this prevent the regex from matching the 2nd string? Is it because there is a space between them and that isn't one of the characters you allowed to match in the parentheses?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: in the expression I wrote you need the closing `>>` right after the string, another string or even a space is not allowed. You can allow spaces with ` *` before the closing part if that is what you want to allow, still two strings won't be matched.